# I need Help to bind dropdown using datasource?

Tags: asp.net

[When i select country then automatic state are display using dropdown data source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1GN9.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Please do so, especially [ask] and [mcve], before posting your next question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple Using c# and linq.

Try this code.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlstate" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlstate_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static">
                            </asp:DropDownList>

  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddldistric" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="0">-Select District-</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>

 protected void ddlstate_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                get_Distric(Convert.ToInt32(ddlstate.SelectedValue));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }



public void get_Distric(Int32 stateid)
        {
            try
            {
                var qry = (db.MasterDistrics.Where(s => s.Status == 1 && s.StateID == stateid).Select(a => new { a.ID, a.Name })).ToList();

                ddldistric.DataSource = qry;
                ddldistric.DataTextField = "Name";
                ddldistric.DataValueField = "ID";
                ddldistric.DataBind();
                ddldistric.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--- Select District ---", "0"));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }
```

Comment: can you explain this    var qry = (db.MasterDistrics.Where(s => s.Status == 1 && s.StateID == stateid).Select(a => new { a.ID, a.Name })).ToList();

Comment: This db.masterDistrics is my table name.

Comment: but sir it direct access posible

Comment: Yes. Using linq in asp.net  this is possible.